# How to reduce the size of a.out ? [ Unix Platform ]

Tags: unix, gcc, output

While compiling a C program in unix platform, is it possible to use any options with gcc or cc compiler so that the size of executable file (generally a.out unless otherwise mentioned) can be reduced.

For eg,

After compiling I find my a.out is  say 1mb in size.
Is it possible to compile the same source code such that the size of a.out reduces to a substantial amount (say 300 kb ) 
(Please ignore this size values as I am randomly putting them)

This kind of requirement generally comes when we are supposed to handover the executable to client. Thus we need to make sure its size is least possible.

Comment: The size of the executable isn't generally an issue for a client unless we're talking ridiculous sizes (takes too long to download, or won't fit on a DVD). But, you can get a little bit of a reduction (not at all a 3x as your example) using compiler optimization options that optimize for size. Alternatively, you can use dynamic libraries but then the total size of the package isn't reduced unless you can count on your client already having some of the needed dynamic libraries available without you having to provide them.

Comment: You can also strip the symbols. Unix command `strip` for example after link-time, or use `gcc -s` to strip down while linking.